# Generate multiple Visio files from a database

Tags: database, ms-access, diagram, visio

I have an Access database containing information about multiple clients.
I can put these datas into one table (1 row = 1 client).
I want to create vsd files from this table. I want to draw a Template and associate forms with fields.

I'm new in Visio, but I succeed in mapping a table to a draw, but I don't know how to ask Visio to generate a file per row. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you upload an image of what you expect each file would look like? That would make it easier to answer this question.

Comment: Just imagine the row contains the IP adresses of the routers of one client for exemple. On my Template, I have the routers and I just need to complete the draw with the IP adresses. As the IP adresses I have several other datas to write on the draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, so I wrote a PowerShell script to do the job.
For each row, it open and edit the Template and save it Under a new name.